# How to make an external database query iterable?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following code:

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'tectcom',                     
        'USER': 'test',                    
        'PASSWORD': '***146***',                 
        'HOST': '',                     
        'PORT': '',                      
    },

    'cdr': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ast',                     
        'USER': '123',                      
        'PASSWORD': '654',                 
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',                     
    }
```

**views.py**

```
def cdr_user(request):
        cursor = connections['cdr'].cursor()
        calls = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM cdr')
        return render_to_response("cdr_user.html",
                {'result':calls }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**cdr_user.html**

```
{% for res in result %}

{{ res.billsec }}<br />

{% endfor %}
```

The table is like that:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| calldate    | datetime     | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       | 
| clid        | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| src         | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| dst         | varchar(80)  | NO   | MUL |                     |       | 
| dcontext    | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| channel     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| dstchannel  | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| lastapp     | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| lastdata    | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| duration    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       | 
| billsec     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       | 
| disposition | varchar(45)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| amaflags    | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0                   |       | 
| accountcode | varchar(20)  | NO   | MUL |                     |       | 
| userfield   | varchar(255) | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| uniqueid    | varchar(32)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| linkedid    | varchar(32)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| sequence    | varchar(32)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
| peeraccount | varchar(32)  | NO   |     |                     |       | 
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

The problem is that I get a **"Exception Value: 'long' object is not iterable"**

```
TypeError at /cdr_user/
'long' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/cdr_user/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'long' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 144
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:    
['/home/tectadmin/cdr/billing',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_endless_pagination-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sab, 1 Set 2012 19:56:10 -0300
Error during template rendering

In template /home/tectadmin/cdr/billing/config/templates/cdr_user.html, error at line 21
'long' object is not iterable
11    text-indent: 6em;
12  }
13  </style>
14  {% extends "index_cliente.html" %}
15  {% load endless %}
16  {% block title %}CDR{% endblock %}
17  {% block content %}
18  
19  
20  
21  {% for res in result %}
22  
23  {{ res.billsec }}<br />
24  
25  {% endfor %}
26  
27  
28  
29  
30  <br />
31  <form name="input" action="/user_cdr/" method="et" >
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/tectadmin/cdr/billing/config/views.py in cdr_user
                {'result':result }, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) ...
▶ Local vars
```

How do I make result iterable to show it in my template?
I've seen https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/  and also other documentation, but I'm still lost in the code.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the full traceback of the `Exception Value: 'long' object is not iterable` error?

Comment: ok, I pasted all the Exception.

Comment: Why are you running raw SQL in a Django application (rather than using their ORM to store objects?)?

Comment: The table cdr is not a model of my project, it's part of another non-django project. Can I use ORM in this case?

Comment: No. I do understand what you need to do, though. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: I have database with my customer's calls.
My customers want to access their call history.
So when one customer enter in the system he'll see the calls, but the table with the calls is in another database.

Comment: @LeandroAbilio @DavidRobinson It involves some work, but Django provides a command line tool to introspect legacy databases, and create model modules out of it. I however would prefer to do this by hand using `Meta.db_tale` and `Field.db_column`. Of course, for this tables to be used as Django models they must complain with certain conditions, and it requires good understanding of the legacy database schema and how Django models works. You would also need to setup database routers to correctly route saves and reads from the correct database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate over the result of a SQL query in Python, use `cursor.fetchall()` to turn it into a list of lists. There's a very handy recipe [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577186-accessing-cursors-by-field-name/) for turning those results into an object you can easily access:

```
class SQLRow(object):
    def __init__(self, cursor, row):
        for (attr, val) in zip((d[0] for d in cursor.description), row) :
            setattr(self, attr, val)
```

Once you have that class, this is simple:

```
def cdr_user(request):
    cursor = connections['cdr'].cursor()
    calls = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM cdr')
    result = [SQLRow(cursor, r) for r in cursor.fetchall()]
    return render_to_response("cdr_user.html",
            {'result': result }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This way, the `billsec` attribute (and all other attributes) will still be accessible in your template.

Comment: It work perfectly, thank you a lot!! If you need anything about telephony, just tell me.

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.execute()` doesn't return an iterable. It modifies the cursor object in place. Here's some [documentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) on this.

You need to call `.fetchone()` `.fetchmany()` or `.fetchall()` to retrieve the results, which should be iterables, e.g.:

```
def cdr_user(request):
  cursor = connections['cdr'].cursor()
  cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM cdr')
  calls = cursor.fetchall()
  return render_to_response("cdr_user.html",
                            {'result':calls }, 
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This wouldn't work with the template as he has it (couldn't be accessed with `res.billsec`).