# creating a results page in django

Tags: django, forms

I am creating my first web app and am trying to understand how to write a page which shows the results of a submitted form and would like some guidance on how to do this.

I have written a form which is working. The form runs some apis that output the results in to a database. I would like to show the values from the database in a results page. The database has a table that holds an test ID which is created when the form is submitted. I can get the ID from the database by doing a

```
select max(id) from test
```

So if i were a user and submitted a form, I would like to be directed to the results page for that ID. So say if the test ID was 10, the url should be http://  /results/id where the id is the value returned by select max(id) from test. I thought about using a hidden field to grab the ID in the form so I can use this to create the url. Has anyone got any ideas on how to do this.

Thanks - Vioilly

Comment: Follow the django tutorial. A large part of django's power and convenience is the ORM. If you do not wish to use that, consider other frameworks.

Comment: I have looked at the tutorials however they don't cover using an external database. Is it not recommended to use an external database then? The database has a large schema and importing it to the django ORM is a lot of work. Although possible, it seems an overkill. Can I use both? One for the results page and one to show the external database values?

Comment: You can use an external database, and if you want to, that's fine. However, this question does not appear to be about using external databases - it appears to be about how to display the results of a submission by the user. That definitely is covered by the tutorial.

Comment: Show us some code for what you have tried

Comment: @marcin - I will go and look at the tutorials and thank you for your help. I have been studying them so hopefully I will get there. Karthikr. I haven't got any code yet for my results page. I have a working form. I have seen this post which I am also going to look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232244/how-to-make-an-external-database-query-iterable

Comment: Django tutorial is very good so should answer all your questions about form submission. However I agree with Marcin that one of the best things about Django is its ORM so if you won't be using it, then you should take a look at some other frameworks such as Pyramid, or something more light-weight such as Bottle or Flask.

Comment: Another though for external database is to look into SQL Alchemy. It is an excellent tool which allows you to use ORM with existing database schemas which do not necessarily follow the Django db patterns. In it you can map class (model) attributes to specific columns in your db. The only thing as far as I know is that it does not play nice with Django. Pyramid is then a better choice.

Comment: @miki725 AFAIK, it's not that SQLAlchemy doesn't play nicely with django, it's that much of django's functionality assumes it has a django-orm-backed database, so you might want to have one of those too for things like users. As you note, Pyramid is designed to use sqlalchemy, which will make the impedance-mismatch go away.

Comment: @Marcin Speaking of Users, it has been in works for some time, but last week on DjangoCon it was confirmed that in 1.5, contrib.Auth will be decoupled from Django. Hopefully videos will be released soon. Here is even the song from the conference about that: http://justinholmes.bandcamp.com/track/john-q-contrib-dot-auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running something like get max id from database is rather bad. What if someone else posts a form right after you and you get that id as maximum?

Rather do something like that (in case of modelforms)

```
if form.is_valid():
  o = form.save()
  return HttpResponseRedirect('results/'+str(o.id)+'/')
```

Alan

Comment: Great - that makes sense.. looks like what I need to do too.